# Excel VBA Get adjacent userform control value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with several rows of textboxes. As I loop through the controls, I'm concatenating the textbox values for a final string. Rather than looping through every textbox, I am only looping through the first textbox in the row and trying to assign a value to a variable with the `replace` method.

What I've tried: `TBvalue = Replace(ctl.Name, "Textbox1", "Textbox2")`

followed by
`TBvalue2 = OnboardingLogForm.TBvalue.value`

Also tried: `TBvalue = OnboardingLogForm.Textbox & i.value` when iterating with i

How can I get the values of other textboxes without statically referring to them?

Comment: Perhaps useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750281/vba-loop-through-textbox-controls-in-userform, or maybe https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer. Thanks for your help.

`Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).value`

Or, if there's any number order to your control names, you can try:

```
For Each ctl In Userform1.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls
    blah = Me.Controls(Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox1", "TextBox2")).value
Next
```